# Stating the further reference of an individual

Tags: grammar, british-english

If I addressed a professor in text as "George Lee Peterson" but didn't want to call him that every single time he is referenced, can I not just state at the first mention of his name like this?:

> George Lee Peterson (Peterson) was born in North eastern Canada in Trenton, Ontario on a small farm. He worked on said farm until he had enough money to go to school. Peterson then continued to major in physiology.

(Horrible grammar I know, but I just need the answer for the question. )

Comment: Ugh - don't put spaces before commas and full stops.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to repeat the surname in brackets after the full name. Using just his surname in later sentences is normal practice and doesn't require explanation. To be more polite you could refer to him as 'Prof. Peterson' instead.

Incidentally, to 'address' someone means to speak or write to them. If you are writing about the professor you are 'referring to' him.

Comment: As a small but notable exception, one place where such explicit notes *are* commonly seen is in contracts and other formal legal documents where precision and avoidance of ambiguity are essential. In such contexts you might encounter phrases like "here(in)after referred to as" (about which [we already have a question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7645/word-for-from-this-point-of-the-document-on-it-will-be-called-simply-xyz)).